# Why does following program shows error Q and D are not declared?

Tags: filter, verilog

I wrote this program for an FIR filter and used D flip flop for delay. I needed to implement filter with Impulse response h(n) = {1, -1}

Despite various efforts, it shows the same error that D and Q aren't defined/ declared properly. There was another error saying Q has been illegally redeclared, for that, I deleted the line where I defined Q output register, in the second module. Please point out to the error and tell me how to fix it.

```
module firfilter( dout, din, clock); 
input din, clock;
output dout; 

parameter b0 = 1'd1; 
parameter b1 = 1'd1;

assign dout = b0 - b1 * Q;

always@ (posedge clock) 

        D < = din; 

endmodule

module dff ( D, clock, Q); 
input D, clock; 
output Q; 


always@ (posedge clock) 

       Q <=  #(1) D; 

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

In verilog all signals declared in module are only visible in this module. You have ports D and Q declared as input and output ports of module dff which is ok, but you are trying to use D and Q in firfilter module which doesn't know anything about D and Q from module dff. What you should do is put an instance of module dff in module firfilter and connect its ports to signals like this:

```
module firfilter( 
    input din, 
    input clock,
    output dout 
);
   parameter b0 = 1'd1; 
   parameter b1 = 1'd1;

   wire Q;
   reg D;
   // instance of dff module:
   dff dff_inst(.D(D), .clock(clock), .Q(Q) ); 

   assign dout = b0 - b1 * Q;

   always@ (posedge clock) 
      D <= din;     
endmodule

module dff (   
   input D, 
   input clock,
   output reg Q
);
   always@ (posedge clock) 
       Q <=  #(1) D; 

endmodule
```

Also you need to know that you cannot drive wire signals inside always blocks so I changed them to regs.

Pay more attention to code formatting as your snippet is barely readable.